# How to remove strings between between parentheses (or any char) in DataFrame?

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a string of number chars that I want to change to type int, but I need to remove the parentheses and the numbers in it (it's just a multiplier for my application, this is how I get the data).

Here is the sample code.

```
import pandas as pd

voltages = ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '310.000 (31)', '300.000 (30)', '190.000 (19)', '0', '20.000 (2)']

df = pd.DataFrame(voltages, columns=['Voltage'])
df
```

```
Out [1]:
    Voltage
0   0
1   0
2   0
3   0
4   0
5   310.000 (31)
6   300.000 (30)
7   190.000 (19)
8   0
9   20.000 (2)
```

How can I remove the substrings within the parenthesis? Is there a Pandas.series.str way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use str.replace with regex:

```
df.Voltage.str.replace(r"\s\(.*","")                                                                                    
Out: 
0           0
1           0
2           0
3           0
4           0
5     310.000
6     300.000 
7     190.000 
8           0
9     20.000 
Name: Voltage, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use str.split()

```
df_2 = df['Voltage'].str.split(' ', 0, expand = True).rename(columns = {0:'Voltage'})
df_2['Voltage'] = df_2['Voltage'].astype('float')
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, this will work for you:

```
result = source_value[:source_value.find(" (")]
```

NOTE: the find function requires a string as source_value. But if you have parens in your value, I assume it is a string.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the separating character will always be a space then the following is quite a neat way of doing it:

```
voltages = [i.rsplit(' ')[0] for i in voltages]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try this:

```
new_series = df['Voltage'].apply(lambda x:int(x.split('.')[0]))
df['Voltage'] = new_series
```

I hope it helps.